# show a message when updating a custom widget in wordpress backend

Tags: wordpress, widget

I'm developing a custom wordpress widget. The widget needs some data from the user and needs to check this data server-side.

I wrote the code that checks the data inside the function 'update' of the widget. When I press the button save of the widget the function update got called correctly and my validation is executed.

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

    $instance = array();
    foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
        $fieldName = $field['name'];
          $instance[$fieldName] =
          (!empty($new_instance[$fieldName]) strip_tags($new_instance[$fieldName]) : '' );
    }

    $check = validate($new_instance);

    return $instance;
}
```

What I need is to display a message to the user based on the result of the validation. How can I do this? For what I've seen the function update is called through ajax so I can't use an admin notice.

Is it possible?How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
add_action('admin_notices', 'misha_custom_order_status_notices');

 function misha_custom_order_status_notices() {

  global $pagenow, $typenow;
  if( get_transient( 'fx-admin-notice-panel' )){
    echo "<div class=\"updated\"><p>Custom notification comes here</p></div>";
 }
}

public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
      $fieldName = $field['name'];
      $instance[$fieldName] =
        (!empty($new_instance[$fieldName])?
          strip_tags($new_instance[$fieldName]) :
          ''
        );
    }

    $check = validate($new_instance);
    set_transient( 'fx-admin-notice-panel', true, 5 );
    return $instance;
}
```

Comment: This will add a message on the next page load right? The save button generate an ajax save action so I don't have the pageload.